# DSolve returns unevaluated

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I am trying to find a solution to this system of differential equations but the program gives the same output without any messages. I would like help.  Please find the *Mathematica* code posted here:

```
s1 = I Exp[I κ x] (Derivative[1][y][x] - I/2 Δ y[x]) == f u[x] + f γ v[x] ;
s2 = I Exp[-I κ x] (Derivative[1][u][x] + I/2 δ u[x]) == f y[x];
s3 = I Exp[-I κ x] (Derivative[1][v][x] - I/2 δ v[x]) == f γ y[x] ;
system = {s1 , s2, s3};
s = DSolve[system, {y, u, v}, x]
```

Comment: At first blush, this could indicate that `DSolve` does not know how to solve your equation. Do you have reason to believe that an **analytical** solution *should* exist?

Comment: **Maple 2019** can solve.

Comment: A system of two equations was resolved only after converting them into two differential equations of the second order so I think they can have a solution

Comment: @Alrubaie What do you find confusing in this? OP included *code* already. Also, did you know that you can edit your comments within the first five minutes? See that Edit button? It would be helpful to keep the number of comments to a minimum, so important ones do not disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You need to help Mathematica a bit by removing the Exp factors.

Define your system of differential equations.

```
s1 = I Exp[I \[Kappa] x] (Derivative[1][y][x] - I/2 \[CapitalDelta] y[x]) == f u[x] + f \[Gamma] v[x];
s2 = I Exp[-I \[Kappa] x] (Derivative[1][u][x] + I/2 \[Delta] u[x]) == f y[x];
s3 = I Exp[-I \[Kappa] x] (Derivative[1][v][x] - I/2 \[Delta] v[x]) == f \[Gamma] y[x];
system = {s1, s2, s3}
```

Transform the system to cancel out the Exp factors.

```
u[x_] = E^(I x \[Kappa]) u1[x];
v[x_] = E^(I x \[Kappa]) v1[x];
y[x_] = y1[x];
```

Solve the transformed system.

```
DSolve[system, {y1, u1, v1}, x]
```

[verbose solution omitted]

Back-substitute to obtain the required solution.

Comment: Thank you 'so much for this good idea it's really effective @Stephen Luttrell